# Error of docker checkpoint

Tags: docker, checkpoint

When I set up the docker development environment and used the `docker checkpoint` command to dump container, errors came. Here is the message:

```
    ERRO[0015] docker-runc did not terminate sucessfully: CRIU version check failed: 
read unixpacket @->@: recvmsg: connection reset by peer
```

and

```
     ERRO[2018-06-13T02:24:46.044116002Z] Handler for POST /v1.30/containers/cr/checkpoints 
    returned error: Cannot checkpoint container cr: docker-runc did not terminate sucessfully:
     CRIU version check failed: read unixpacket @->@: recvmsg: connection reset by peer path= /var/run/docker/containerd/daemon/
io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/cf41aa42ca30b619afdd0b01ecfe9e0a7c22a3ff5a2042b6adc7e785bd7a8543/criu-dump.log: unknown
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Why using checkpoint to dump "containers"? It is used to manage checkpoints, which is only some component of your container. Do you have a specific point here?
To manage containers, you can remove the container itself (docker rm <container_id>) it, and/or delete the image (docker images rm) . 
Is your checkpoint an orphan? Have you tried to clean your repo using docker system prune?

Comment: This command is supposed to be able to checkpoint the process in a container. My point is what this error message implies.

Comment: OK, I thought you were trying to do stg else.
Do you have CRIU 2.x+ installed? https://criu.org/Installation

Comment: Are you trying to checkpoint an X application running inside a docker ?